# Ajax request and SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a form that the users complete and then press "Submit" button to register.

I wanted to preview the data to the user before the form is submitted, so i used AJAX to do this. The procedure is as follows:

1) User clicks "submit" button (ex. registration.php)

2) JS script, prevents the default action (which is to submit it) and calls another PHP script via AJAX (**registrationAJAX.php**), that:

a) Performs some database changes

b) stores some variables in a **$_SESSION** array

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = $uID;
$_SESSION['userEmailAddress'] = $email;
$_SESSION['hash'] = $hash;
```

c) json_encodes the following array:

```
$results = array(

                   'result'  => 'success',
                   'message' => 'registration was successful' 

                );

echo json_encode($results);
```

d) then exits

```
exit();
```

3) Back to JS script and on AJAX **success**, i check to see whether the result is "success" and then redirect the user to a script that sends an automated email for account verification:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "js/ajax/registrationAJAX.php",
    data: {form data...},
    cache: false,
    success: function(output){
         var outputJSON = $.parseJSON(output);
         var status = outputJSON.result;

         if(status == 'success')
         {
             location.href = "https://domain.com/verify.php";
         }
    }
});
```

The **verify.php** script MUST have access to the $_SESSION variables to be executed correctly.

```
 //the code will only executed if the $_SESSION['hash'] is set:
 if(isset($_SESSION['hash']))
 {
     //SEND EMAIL ACTIVATION EMAIL TO USER

     //INFORM THE DATABASE THAT THE EMAIL IS SENT
 }
```

Sometimes i see that some of my users don't receiver the activation email. This will happen if the **verify.php** script doesn't have the $_SESSION variables i stored during registrationAJAX.php and then fail (as shown at the code above).

**Question:**

1)Is there a possibility that the variables delay to get stored in the $_SESSION and the redirection to **verify.php** is performed with no $_SESSION variables?

2) Does the exit() command cause a problem?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that cookies could be disabled, which, I guess, would cause complete session loss.

Comment: Does verify.php have `session_start()` at the top of the code?

Comment: Far more likely is the user closes the browser some time after the ajax request is started, but before it finishes, so the redirect is never follwed. Why not send the email in `registrationAJAX.php`?

Comment: Also, make sure you show some visual feedback (such as a spinner spinner) whilst the ajax request is processing

Comment: @Steve That would require one of: slow-ass server, slow-ass internet connection, or very precise timing.

Comment: Point number 2 in your list is fairly frequent, especially with mobile connections. I would say its far more likely than users having cookies off

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, and make sure you're not getting the "Headers already sent" warning from the PHP.

Comment: @Steve Sometimes we don't see the obvious and we try to find a more complicated solution. I will make sure to send the email in the same script to avoid such problems. But since i may come against this issue again, is there something i can do to prevent it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, there is a session_start() at the start of the verify.php script.

Comment: @Siguza , can a client disable the ability to store variables in a SESSION? I thought that SESSIONs are stored server-side, unlike COOKIEs that are store client-side.

Comment: `session` data is saved server side, but it uses a `cookie` to link a user to said data. Its possible to use session without cookies (by using a query string identifier for example) but thats rarely a good idea. You can check a user has cookies enabled in javascript.

Comment: re `"is there something i can do to prevent it"` well you cant stop users leaving your site. You can ensure that any actions that need to be performed together are performed in the same request, not split up into multiple requests

Comment: @Steve Lesson learned the hard way! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider move to OAuth authentication to avoid the issue with the cookies disabled:

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-php-oauth-server/

Regards,